# Using limit definition of a derivative to solve $(x+4)^{2x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$(x+4)^{2x}$

I've tried using log rules and combining exponents and taking the ln of both sides but I can never get the h out of either the exponent or the ln()

Comment: what do you mean with "solve"?

Comment: Find the derivative

Answer (score 1):

Usually one uses logarithmic differentiation:

$$y=(x+4)^{2x}$$

$$\ln(y)=\ln[(x+4)^{2x}]=2x\ln(x+4)$$

Then differentiate, using chain rule on the left, product rule on the right.

Comment: Yeah but I need to solve it using the limit definition of the derivative

Comment: @TristanL If you take a look at this [two variable chain rule using the limit definition of the derivative](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ashenk/Section14_4.pdf), you will find that if we had $$f(u,v)=u^v,\quad u=x+4,\quad v=2x$$ then it is quite obvious what the derivative comes out to be.